# what does this connection string URL means?

Tags: jdbc, soap, ws

I'm working with a SOAP web service and one of the connection strings I was given looks like this

```
https://dominio.subdominio.org/operajserv/ifc8ws/ifc8ws:jdbc/operaopraprdds
```

I usually work with connection strings like

```
jdbc://operaopraprdds
```

Can someone tell me what it means the last part of the string?

```
:jdbc/operaopraprdds
```

Is this some kind of socket to a remote database or what is it?

the database that it is trying to be reach is Oracle in case that helps

Comment: The second and third URLs are not valid connection strings. JDBC connection strings have the form `jdbc:<subprotocol>:<driver-specific>`. The first is a HTTPS URL with a path part `ifc8ws:jdbc`, as to what it actually means depends on what the URL is for and what the underlying application does in response. Without further context, that is not really answerable.

Comment: A quick Google suggests this is something for "Oracle® Hospitality OPERA IFC Controller and Hotel Property Interface", so I'd suggest you read its documentation.